# Not able to exit phonegap application on Back Button of android device

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, back-button-control

I have used following code to exit from application. For first time it works perfectly. But when I opened some next screens and then came back to screen where I wanted to close my application, it fails to close application.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function onLoad() 
    {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        //alert("Load");
    }

    function onDeviceReady() 
    {
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, true);
       // alert("Device Ready");
    }


    function onBackKeyDown() 
    {
        navigator.app.exitApp();        
    }
</script>
```

Please suggest something which will work ....

Comment: Have you tried binding deviceready out of onload?
deviceready fires as soon as the phonegap api are loaded so it may fire even before your onLoad function executes

Comment: Did it work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should delete navigation history on page load so whenever you press the back button it will exit the app automatically.

```
        if (typeof navigator.app !== 'undefined') {
            navigator.app.clearHistory();
        }
```

Above code will work. Since navigator.app is undefined for iOS, this will work cross platform.